# How to modify an array of objects containing values of the same name?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Given the following array of nested objects:

```
    var existingArray = [{
            "content": {
                "host": {
                    "name": "Mia"
                }
            },
        }, {
            "content": {
                "host": {
                    "name": "Annie"
                }
            },
        }, {
            "content": {
                "host": {
                    "name": "Mia"
                }
            },
            ,
            {
                content: {
                    host: {
                        name: "Oscar"
                    }
                },
            },
            {
                "content": {
                    "host": {
                        "name": "Annie"
                    }
                },
            },
            {
                "content": {
                    "host": {
                        "name": "Mia"
                    }
                },
            },
            {
                "content": {
                    "host": {
                        "name": "Annie"
                    }
                },
            }
        ];
```

How would I modify the object's name value if they match -- to differentiate them?

To produce a new array, such as:

```
        var existingArray = [{
            "content": {
                "host": {
                    "name": "Mia"
                }
            },
        }, {
            "content": {
                "host": {
                    "name": "Annie"
                }
            },
        }, {
            "content": {
                "host": {
                    "name": "Mia_2"
                }
            },
            ,
            {
                content: {
                    host: {
                        name: "Oscar"
                    }
                },
            },
            {
                "content": {
                    "host": {
                        "name": "Annie_2"
                    }
                },
            },
            {
                "content": {
                    "host": {
                        "name": "Mia_3"
                    }
                },
            },
            {
                "content": {
                    "host": {
                        "name": "Annie_3"
                    }
                },
            }
        ];
```

I need to keep the structure of the array nearly identical--with just updates to the duplicate name values.

The reason I need this is because I am using a plugin that checks for duplicate names and then combines them (the how's or why's are too complicated to post here.)

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: This is pretty straight forward, have you tried anything?

Comment: Honestly, I've been working for days and am pretty tired -- hence being lazy and posting this.  Was hoping someone would have a quick answer.

Comment: Suggestion: loop every name and keep adding to a new array with count. Every name from `existingArray` you check the temporary array, if it's already inserted there, change the name from `existingArray` adding `_ count+1`, if it's not in the temp, add to it and go to next name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might work for you:

```
var i;
var k;
for(i = 0; i < existingArray.length; i++){
    var count = 2;
    for(k = 0; k < existingArray.length; k ++){
        if(i != k && existingArray[i].content.host.name === existingArray[k].content.host.name){
            existingArray[k].content.host.name += '_' + count;
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is close --just keeps appending "_1" to all of the values instead of appending them to the duplicates.: http://jsfiddle.net/ansible/uvx4zeeh/

Comment: change to `if(i!=k && existingArray[i].content.host.name === existingArray[k].content.host.name){` and start `count = 2;`

Comment: @FirstOne looks like there might be a syntax error there.

Answer (score 0):

Keep an object with each name used as the key and the number of times it was used as the value.

Then reference it in each iteration to see if name was already used.

If it wasn't used yet, add it to the array and set it to 1. In this case, the name will remain the same.

If it was already used, increment it's value in the array. In this case, the name will be the name plus '_' plus the value stored in the object using name as key.

```js
var existingArray = [  
   {  
      "content":{  
         "host":{  
            "name":"Mia"
         }
      }
   },
   {  
      "content":{  
         "host":{  
            "name":"Annie"
         }
      }
   },
   {  
      "content":{  
         "host":{  
            "name":"Mia"
         }
      }
   },
   {  
      "content":{  
         "host":{  
            "name":"Oscar"
         }
      }
   },
   {  
      "content":{  
         "host":{  
            "name":"Annie"
         }
      }
   },
   {  
      "content":{  
         "host":{  
            "name":"Mia"
         }
      }
   },
   {  
      "content":{  
         "host":{  
            "name":"Annie"
         }
      }
   }
]
,   usedNames = {}
,   newArray = []
,   result = ''
;
for(var index = 0; index < existingArray.length; index ++) {
    var name = existingArray[index]['content']['host']['name'];
    newArray.push(existingArray[index]);
    if(typeof usedNames[name] !== 'number') {
        usedNames[name] = 1;
        newArray[index]['content']['host']['name'] = name;
    } else {
        usedNames[name] ++;
        newArray[index]['content']['host']['name'] = name + '_' + usedNames[name];
    }
    result += 'content: host: name: ' + newArray[index]['content']['host']['name'] + '<br/>';
}
document.write(result);
```

Comment: Did my comment on the question inspire you?

Comment: @FirstOne Nope. I saw that after.